# SQL foreign key delete cascading

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I appear to be having an issue on a SQL server that has recently been upgraded, we previously didn't manage the server be we now do this inhouse.

When a user updates a table that has a FK on it, it appears to be cascading the a delete command through the table that have the linked FK.

Any ideas or do you think this is being caused by another issue?

Sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascading delete is an option on the actual foreign key relationship.  Find the relationship is Management Studio and choose "Modify", and you should be able to see Delete Rule:Cascade under "Insert and Update Specification".

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a cascading delete from an update. Check the triggers on your table.